# Javascript different behaviour when debugging in MS EDGE

Tags: javascript, ajax, microsoft-edge

I need to copy to clipboard a text from a page but I'm facing some issues, since the code isn't working but when I use the debugger to see what happens it works properly.

The code runs when an ajax call is sent like this:

```
function printRelatedContent(key, nodeId, name) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "getNodeProperties.web",
        data : {
            nodeId : nodeId
        },
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
            var divCopy = $('<div/>', {
                'id' : 'copy-button' + key,
                'class' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate',
                'style' : 'cursor:pointer;margin-left: 10px;',
                'title' : 'Copy to clipboard'
            });
            $('#modalRelatedLabel').append(divCopy);
            divCopy.unbind('click').click(function() {
                //workaround to copy to clipboard in MS Edge since old clipboardData.setData isn't working anymore
                var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
                textArea.value = name;
                document.body.appendChild(textArea);
                textArea.select();
                try {
                    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
                    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
                    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
                }
                document.body.removeChild(textArea);
            });
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem as I say is that it's not working at all (event though the console log says it's successful), but when I put a breakpoint in any place of the code it works like charm and copies the text to the clipboard.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is quite a lot of code here. Could you please omit unnecessary details?

Comment: Why don't you use [Clipboard.writeText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) instead of adding and styling a new element to the DOM only to remove it later!

Comment: @phuzi, it seems it requires secure login, which is not the case: stackoverflow.com/questions/51805395/…. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @xamgore yep, you're right, sorry... but since i have to adapt my code to edege browser and i have no idea how to make it work, I took this piece of code from this example: blog.codeinside.eu/2016/05/12/copy-to-clipboard-with-javascript. I'll try to remove all the styling stuff and see if it's still working (in debug mode, of course)

Comment: `divCopy.unbind('click').click(function() {...}`, Can this part of the code be executed correctly? I'm not sure how to design your page. If possible, could you provide a simple sample code snippet of the page to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thank you @XudongPeng, I finally changed the whole thing to https and it's working like charm with a simple nvigator.clipboard.writeText()... it was easier than this hell :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed the whole thing to https and it's working like charm with a simple Clipboard.writeText(), as @phuzi suggested, instead the awful textArea thing. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can put it as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.